# How may I get the value from a twig variable using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

i'm trying to get a value from a DateType in Twig using Jquery.

I tried to assign a data-class to my twig variable. 
And then get it from JQuery using .attr() or .data() with no success.

Twig:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.dateDeb,"Date de début",{'label_attr':{'class':'col- 
    xs-12 control-label'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.dateDeb)}}
    <div class="col-xs-12"  id="idDateDeb" data-id="{{ form.dateDeb}}">
        {{ form_widget(form.dateDeb,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#idDateDeb').change(function(){
    alert("On change le datetime");
   var maDateActuelle = $(this).attr('data-id');
   alert(maDateActuelle);
});
```

I expect the output of the date chosen like 06/02/2019. Instead i got an error that this object could not be converted to string.

How may I process to get the date ?

Thank you for your replies !

Comment: can you show the rendered html so we can see the format of the variables and attributes

Comment: I'm not sure what are you doing with `change` event put on`div`. You would normally attach `change` to forms `input`, `select` and etc. https://api.jquery.com/change/ And as previously mentioned, the rendered html would be a massive help.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would put a `change` event handler on a `div`, but in any case your code works fine with the data you specified: https://jsfiddle.net/4w03jme5/. Please edit the question to show a case which presents the error you describe

Comment: The error you are getting is on the following line, `data-id="{{ form.dateDeb}}"` as you didn't provide any information about what this variable holds it hard to say what the solution should be

Comment: I found the solution. I simply add an id into my form_widget(form.dateDeb) then i access to this id with javascript using document.getElementById('id). Then I use function .value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<div class="col-xs-12"  id="idDateDeb" data-id="{{ form.dateDeb.vars.id}}">`